# Manipulating pixels using only toDataURL

Tags: javascript, image, binary, pixel

The problem I have is this:  I need to be able to dynamically tint an image using Javascript, but I cannot access pixel data via the canvas.  I can, however, store the dataURL (or any other text-based data format) and include that with the code, manipulate that data, and then create an image object using that dataURL.

My question is, how can I access the RGBA value of each pixel, given only the dataURL.  I assume I need to decode the base64 url, but into what format in order to manipulate on the pixel level?  And then would be it be as trivial as re-encoding it as base64, slapping it in a url, and the passing to an image?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to manipulate the image, or just how it appears to the user?

Comment: Seems like you'd have to write the JPEG (or PNG or whatever) decompression yourself.

Comment: You could create a hidden canvas element, draw your image there, do the tint, and then pull the dataURL from the hidden canvas.

Comment: The problem is, I am working in Palm webOS, which doesn't allow dataURL (or imageData) to be pulled from the canvas.  I can only start off with the hardcoded data, modify it, and then use it as the src for an image to draw to the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented a toDataURL/PNG replacement over at xda that may serve your needs. It operates on an RGBA array, so you could include your image as an uncompressed resource, load it into an array using a simple XMLHttpRequest, manipulate it and finally feed it into that function to get a drawable DataURL

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1251575